# The elements of a perfect juicy jump

Tags: javascript, platformer

I have seen and implemented these ideas: [Simple Physics based Movement SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667034/simple-physics-based-movement). [Building a Better Jump GDC Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG9SzQxaCm8). And written a tutorial about it [Making a Platformer in Pico 8](https://github.com/eguneys/celeste-jumping).
Finally made a simple game [Coler Js2020](https://github.com/eguneys/js2020) using these ideas. People have complained the player is too fast, or the springs are not right.

But I want better,more juicy, control over player jump. Like as if I am drawing the trajectory. I don't want real life physics. I want juicy physics where it just feels right, like float-y in SMB or stiff like in Celeste, or Spelunky.

Maybe we can model this in terms of a sound envelope:

`Attack` is time it takes to reach peak of the jump.
`Decay` is time it takes to reach sustain level from the peak.
`Sustain` is, time to stay at maximum height, until the button is released or some timeout.
`Release` is the time to go to ground from maximum height.

I am studying Celeste source code so far I have this:

```
// p.dx p.dy is the velocity
// p.x p.y is computed through this velocity elsewhere.
// mu.appr(value, target, amount) returns value approached to target by specified amount. like `lerp`.

const JumpGraceTime = 4;
const DuckFriction = 0.1;
const MaxRun = 4;
const RunReduce = 0.3;
const RunAccel = 0.3;
const Gravity = 8;
const MaxFall = 4;
const FastMaxAccel = 0.5;
const JumpHBoost = 0.1;
const JumpSpeed = -6;
const LiftBoost = 0.3;

function update() {
  let onGround = false;
  if (p.dy >= 0) {
    if (base.isSolid(0, 1)) {
      onGround = true;
    }
  }
 let maxDx = MaxRun;
  if (Math.abs(p.dx) > maxDx && Math.sign(p.dx) == inputX) {
    p.dx = mu.appr(p.dx, maxDx * inputX, RunReduce);
  } else {
    p.dx = mu.appr(p.dx, maxDx * inputX, RunAccel);
  }
  p.dx = mu.appr(p.dx, 0, DuckFriction);

  let maxFall = MaxFall;
  let mf = MaxFall;
  maxFall = mu.appr(maxFall, mf, FastMaxAccel);


  let maxDy = maxFall;
  p.dy = mu.appr(p.dy, maxDy, Gravity);

  if (onGround) {
    jGrace = JumpGraceTime;
  } else if (jGrace > 0) {
    jGrace--;
  }

  if (jBuffer > 0) {
    if (jGrace > 0) {
    let liftBoost = fLiftBoost();
    p.dx += JumpHBoost * inputX;
    p.dy = JumpSpeed;
    p.dx += liftBoost[0];
    p.dy += liftBoost[1];
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there are a lot of tweakable parameters, and I don't even know if I need them or use them correctly.
Maybe I can configure these parameters through an interface and test my player there, but is that the best approach.
Currently using the above code, my movement sucks.
Can you suggest me the ultimate techniques to implement a juicy jump that can fit all sizes.

Comment: This question presumes there is one universal, ultimate way to implement a jump "that can fit all sizes". I don't believe that is true. There are various techniques that have proven to be versatile, and it's clear from your question you've already studied some of the best references out there. To go beyond this, and find the right jump *for your game*, you'll need to start grappling not with the ultimate/perfect/universal principles of all jumps, but with the particular traits of your specific game. Can you narrow down one specific aspect of your current jump that feels wrong for your game?

Comment: I don't have a specific vision for my jump, but looking for a direction to go to where I see a viable technique. For example my player doesn't stay in the air enough and is too fast going up and down. Also there is a bug where it jerks If I double press jump after touching the ground.

Comment: Great. Editing your question to ask "How to control the hang time duration, rising and falling speeds in a jump" would likely get you more constructive, useful answers than asking for "ultimate" "perfection".

Comment: In particular, when you say "Like as if I am drawing the trajectory", have you [considered doing exactly that](https://twitter.com/nanobody_/status/842341845619380224), as [these developers have](https://twitter.com/psychicparrot/status/976877941543055360)?